# Complexity of inverting a diagonal matrix

Tags: complexity-theory, computation-models, numerical-algorithms

What is the complexity of inverting a $n \times n$ diagonal matrix?

From what I learn in algebra, the inverse of a diagonal matrix is obtained by replacing each element in the diagonal with its reciprocal.

So is it correct to say that the complexity of inverting a diagonal matrix is $\mathcal{O}(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what $n$ is in your question. If your matrix has dimensions $n \times n$ and your model of computation allows you to perform
basic arithmetic operations in constant time then, yes, computing the inverse matrix takes $O(n)$ time.

Comment: I forgot to mention the dimension of the matrix, sorry about that. Then is the exact cost of operation is equal to $n$?

Comment: Although it does depend on the representation of your matrix. If it is not represented in a sparse way (a sparse representation could for example simply be an array of the diagonal elements) then the output size is $\Omega(n^2)$ and so you'll need quadratic time, most of it spent writing zeros.

Comment: @TR The "exact cost" is as Steven says $O(n)$.

Comment: @Tassle Yes, that depends on the representation, but if the operation is essentially the pointwise reciprocal for $O(n)$ elements, I think it is fair to say that you can perform that in $O(n)$ time.  You can then return those elements, and the "user" can do with them as they please, e.g. in $O(n)$ time insert them into the matrix.

Comment: @PålGD I thought $\mathcal{O}(n)$ is just an estimation of the cost instead of the exact cost? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: @TR To be precise the cost is $\Theta(n)$ (assuming a reasonable representation for the input and output matrix), meaning that there is some function $f(n) \in \Theta(n)$ such that the cost is $f(n)$. The notation $\Theta(n)$ is essentially discarding multiplicative and additive constants. It doesn't make much sense to analyze the time complexity at a finer level of detail as it would depend on  the specifics of the architecture, programming language, compiler, input/output encoding, etc... that you are using.